# Unable to use URL as a link from Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way that a URL can be saved in Firestore so that it can be used as a link to an external website? Or is there another way around this?

Currently, I've got multiple documents in a collection that all have the same format as below;

| Field | Content | Field Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| contactName | John Doe | string |
| contactNumber | 1234567890 | num |
| contactAddress | 1234 Anywhere St | string |
| contactEmail | example@example.com | string |
| contactWebsite | http://www.example.com | string |

I'm able to map through all of the documents without a problem. The bit where I'm coming unstuck is passing the website into a Link tag and attaching the link to the contact name. Apologies if that doesn't make sense hopefully, the code below will make it clearer...

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

<div className="contact-details">
  <Link to={{pathname:"{props.contact.contactWebsite}"}} target="_blank">
    {props.contact.contactName}
  </Link>
  Contact Number: {props.contact.contactNumber}
  Contact Address: {props.contact.contactAddress}
  Contact Email: {props.contact.contactEmail}
</div>
```

In its current form, the code works, but when the link is clicked, it opens my 404 page rather than opening a new tab with the chosen website.

Comment: If you console.log props.contact.contactWebsite, what does it show?

Comment: I'd also try using a template literal. Using backticks ``${props.contact.contactWebsite}``

Comment: I agree with Joel's approach, just use the template literal it should open

Comment: @JoelHager logging to the console shows all the contacts websites as expected i.e. `http://www.examle.com/`  Where exactly do the backticks need to go? I've tried every combination I can think of and it still opens the 404 page.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use the `<Link>` component with this? If the website is external, it doesn't need routing, no? Try <a href={props.contact.contactWebsite}>{props.contact.contactWebsite}</a>

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, a URL is just a string at the end of the day. you can encode it using `encodeURIcompnent` if you want to ensure characters are escaped.
Once you pull it from firestore, you can process the URL as needed (https, and so on) and then insert it as an `<img>` `src` value, or hand it to the `window.location`.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent